# Select Option for a field not related to anything?

Tags: django

How would you handle a scenario with a floating inline table that is a dimension in a pre-existing database that doesn't relate to the user in anyway?  The goal is to load this table into a select option in a template, then post a save to the database on a submit.  So there will be a relationship from the request to Table 1 at a later point in my model, going from the Request model to the Table1 model.

The model:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_Num', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  
    field2 = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Table1'
```

The view i'm not sure about but i think it would be:

```
   table1 = Table1.objects.all()

args = {'table1':table1}

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

Now to populate the select I tried the following in my template but it just puts a bunch of empty boxes:

```
{% for table in table1 %}
     <select table1select="Choose a Option..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
       <option value="{{table1.field1}}"></option>
     </select>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm guessing it's empty because there is no relationship to the User, but i just want to list every row in the database for field1.

I added a screen shot of what i'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should access `field1` from table variable instead of `table1`, so I guess this is the right code:

```
 <select table1select="Choose a Option..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
     {% for table in table1 %}
         <option value="{{table.field1}}">{{table.field1}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it produces the same results as the above.  I'm assuming I don't need the forloop either.  I also added a picture of what I'm seeing in the edit.

Comment: I updated my picture to what i'm seeing, the select appears to be blank. After I changed my forloop's location.

Comment: Because you didn't set the text of each select option
if you want to show field1 in the select, edit the option tag in the previous code to this, as the value attribute in option tag is irrelevant to the text that appears.
`<option value="{{table.field1}}">{{table.field1}}</option>`

Comment: That was the missing part, thank you Ahmad.  I'll mark this correct if you could update the solution for others that would be great.

Comment: for my understanding what does the > after the value do?

Comment: The '>' wasn't the something you are missing, It is part of the html tag, every html tag is constructed in this way:
`<tag-name attribute1="..." attribute2="..." ...>tag-text....</tag-name>`
So the last edit was to set the text of each option tag of the select tag while the value attribute sets the value that is sent from the form when this option is selected.